# Distinct in concatenated columns from a table in ms sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, concatenation, distinct, distinct-values

I run this query in my db the results are not distinct. Is there any solution to get the distinct results while using concatenation in select clause.

```
select
    case 
        when c.SubtypeId_FK is null then c.TypeDescription 
        else c.TypeDescription + ' In ' + cs.Subtype 
    end as Experties
from 
    CaseTLS c, 
    CaseLawyer cl , 
    Lawyer l , 
    CaseSubtype cs
where
    c.CaseId = cl.CaseID  
    and cl.ComputerCode = l.ComputerCode 
    and l.ComputerCode = @p1 
    and (
        c.SubtypeId_FK = cs.SubtypeId or c.SubtypeId_FK is null
    )
```

Comment: Use `select Distinct case..`. If possible add sample data and expected output which will help you to get proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use Distinct in select clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
     DISTINCT case 
        when c.SubtypeId_FK is null then c.TypeDescription 
        else c.TypeDescription + ' In ' + cs.Subtype 
    end as Experties
from 
    CaseTLS c, 
    CaseLawyer cl , 
    Lawyer l , 
    CaseSubtype cs
where
    c.CaseId = cl.CaseID  
    and cl.ComputerCode = l.ComputerCode 
    and l.ComputerCode = @p1 
    and (
        c.SubtypeId_FK = cs.SubtypeId or c.SubtypeId_FK is null
    )
```